# C++ library includes pseudo-inverse of a matrix?

Tags: c++, matlab, armadillo, matrix-inverse

I'm looking for a C++ library that includes pinv (pseudo inverse matrix operation in MATLAB).
I tried to use Armadillo but it lacks of Multi-threaded debug DLL(/MDd), but I need that type of lib for my project . check [this](http://www.fi.muni.cz/~xsvobod2/misc/lapack/).

I would be happy if you can share that version of lib or propose an alternative and lightweight library.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that [boost linear](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm) will have something you need. Just check it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [cv::invert](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?#invert)  function of [OpenCV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/latest/download?source=files) to calculate pseudo-inverse of a matrix.

The library is multi threaded, and uses Intel Thread Building Blocks to accelerate processing.

Answer (score 1):

[Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net) will happily use multi-threaded LAPACK libraries.  Instead of using standard LAPACK, it's simply a matter of linking with a version of LAPACK that has multi-threading.  For example, Intel's [Math Kernel Library (MKL)](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl/).